# Java object comparison: implementing a `compareTo()` method for a playing card game

Tags: java, comparison, object-comparison

I am making a method using the String comparison method "compareTo".
However I have a few questions pertaining as to how exactly it works.

```
 public int compareTo(Card player2){    
    int finalRank = this.getRank().compareTo(player2.getRank());


    int turn = this.getRank().compareTo(player2.getRank());

    // Checks for "War" before anything is processed
    if(this.getRank() == player2.getRank())
    {
    return 0; // results in war
    }

    //This logic sets Ace as the highest card
    //after checking for "WAR"
    else if(this.getRank() == Rank.ACE)
    {
    return 1;
    }


    else if(player2.getRank() == Rank.ACE)
    {
    return -1;
    }


    //If it is not an ace, the winner per turn
    //is determined by standard value.
    else if(turn > 0)
    {
        //System.out.println("playerOne wins");
    return 1;
    }

    else 
    {
        //System.out.println("playerTwo wins");
    return -1;  
    }   

        }//end compareTo
```

This is my portion of code in the compareTo method.
**So that i can mention, I had received quite a bit of online help for this segment of code. While it was being explained to me, it made sense. Thus if it makes sense to me, i should be able to rewrite this segment of code in another format. 
However, i have found myself not being able to do so. Thus i am looking for advice and help.

The function

```
int turn = this.getRank().compareTo(player2.getRank());
```

is generally what throws me off.
What exactly is the compareTo method doing?

for a players turn, it is comparing the two cards at play -> following the programs logic.

Is it possible for me to compare cards with out using the compareTo method?

Here is how i have my class constructors set up.

Again, to finalize. 
I am having issues understanding how the compareTo method works.
and if anything id like suggestions of another way to compare the players cards at play.

**The cards list are coming from 2 seperate classes -> Suit and Rank**

```
private Rank rCard;
  private Suit sCard;
```

/** ********************************************
    * Initializing an object out of class Card
    * @param rCard
    * @param sCard
    * 
    ***********************************************
    */
      public Card(Rank rCard, Suit sCard)
      {
         this.rCard = rCard;
         this.sCard = sCard;
      }

Comment: **Why** do you need another way?

Comment: You didn't post the constructors you mentioned.

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand about `compareTo()`? I don't know the game logic behind this but the method is fairly straight forward, it just does a bunch of comparisons and returns an `int` based on the different scenarios

Comment: Why - I really just want to make sure that i understand the material. Personally i am not comfortable using compareTo. Rather than just copy, pasting what i was given through help. Id prefer to be able to reiterate code, so that i personally feel that i understand it.

Comment: @Mr D - This is for a game of War. 
The reason why i am saying that i do not understand the compareTo() method, is because i cannot use any of the other string comparison methods to make this code work. 
All i can literally do is change the variable names, which wouldnt be satisfying to me.
Bottom line - i am not trying to "Cheat" on this project, but rather receive help and reiterate it into my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the purpose of the `compareTo()` method is to define what makes two objects comparable.  Not all objects are comparable.  Some objects are made comparable by the Java API.  For example, `String` is comparable.  So if you were to use a method such as `Collections.sort(someStringArray)`, this task can be accomplished because the objects are comparable.  On the other hand, if you wanted to `sort()` an array of your `Card` objects, it can't be accomplished until you make the `Card` object comparable.  You do this by using the `compareTo()` method.  You also want to define your `Card` class as `implements Comparable` interface, in which you will have to @Override the `compareTo()` method.  This, will make your `Cards` comparable by rank, *if* you decide to compare them by rank in your `compareTo()`.

What I believe you're trying to is compare the two objects by rank.

```
int turn = this.getRank().compareTo(player2.getRank());

is generally what throws me off. What exactly is the compareTo method doing?
```

You're comparing the rank of `this`, which I'm assuming is `Player1` to the rank of `player2`.  When you use the `compareTo()` method, you return an `int`.  This `int` tells you which player's rank is higher... `1` meaning, `player1`'s rank is higher, `-1` meaning `player2`'s rank is higher, and `0` meaning the ranks are equal.  This `int` I'm assuming will determine whose turn it is

Also, I believe that this:

```
int turn = this.getRank().compareTo(player2.getRank());
```

should be placed outside of the `compareTo()` method and should be change to this:

```
int turn = this.compareTo(player2);
```

You're already comparing the players by their ranks in the `compareTo()`, so you don't need to use `getRank()`.  I don't know if this will solve your problem completely, because I don't have your complete code, but I hope this gives you a better understanding of how the `compareTo()` method works.